# Cutting a surface to make it simply-connected / cutting a surface into a topological disk?

Tags: python, disk, topology

Would you know of any Python implementation (or any implementation at all) of an algorithm than can cut a non simply-connected shape/path (e.g. a polygon with holes) into a simply connected shape/path aka a topological disk (e.g. a polygon without holes).

I found some literature ([Optimally Cutting a Surface into a Disk](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-003-2948-z)) but I could not find any implementation

The fundamental idea of what such an algorithm would achieve is best summarized by the picture below (for the 2D case): given a path (in black) that contains two "subpathes" which define a blue surface with a hole, it would find "a" cut so that the surface can be described as a simply connected region enclosed by a single path.

[image]

Comment: This question calls for a major research effort and is not a good match for SO.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I did not miss anything in my google search and this is just not an algorithm that is readily/publicly available even for the 2D case ? The article I cited mentioned that there were some simple brute force approach, and I was hoping this had been implemented before maybe for texture mapping of non simply connected shapes. Anyway, thank you!